# How do I create conditional relationship in Laravel eloquent on Comma Separated Column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have **4 tables** `vendors`, `project`,`project_quotas` and `project_vendors`

Table Structures:

`vendors: id (Primary), name, email`

`project: id (Primary), name, status`

`project_quotas: quota_id (Primary), project_id (Foreign Key), quota_name, description`

`project_vendors: pv_id (Primary), project_id(Foreign Key), vendor_id, spec_quota_ids(comma separated, Foreign Keys), description`

Lets Say For `project_id = 1`

I want to fetch **All Project Quotas and their Project Vendors**

---

here is Raw query I have created to get this data:

```
SELECT
    pq.id as pq_id, pq.project_id as project_id, pq.name as pq_name, pv.id as pv_id, pv.vendor_id as pv_vendor_id, pv.spec_quota_ids as quotas
FROM `project_quotas` pq
LEFT JOIN
    project_vendors pv ON pv.project_id = 1 AND find_in_set(pq.id, spec_quota_ids) > 0
WHERE pq.project_id = 1
GROUP BY pv.vendor_id, find_in_set(pq.id, spec_quota_ids)
Order BY pq.id
```

Here is the output
[image: Output from this SQL Query]

The only issue is that I want this query to Run Eloquent way.
I have ProjectQuota, ProjectVendors Model 
I want something like

```
$data = ProjectQuota::where('project_id', '=', '1')->with('projectVendors', 'projectVendors.Source')->get();
```

I don't know how can I create a conditional `hasMany`relationship in eloquent, will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I this is the way to do this.

```
if($this->project_id===2) {
    return $this->belongsTo(Foo::class);
}

if($this->project_id===3) {
    return $this->belongsTo(Bar::class);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I couldn't understand your solution.
In ProjectQuota I have to create a has many relationships with ProjectVendors, the issue is that in place of a single foreign key in project_vendors, I have comma separated project_quota ids, like 1,2,3 - 
so when I am fetching records for Quota 1 it should get all project vendors having 1 in those comma separated values column.